# plus minus button for google sheets that applies on entire column

Tags: button, spreadsheet

I have managed to put a plus minus button in my google sheets document but it only applies for one cell. Since I want to use it to update my stock in the sheet i want one button plus and one minus button that applies on multiple columns.

the code i use right now is this

```
function plus() {   
    ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()    
    s=ss.getActiveSheet()
    var currVal=s.getRange("A1").getValue()
    var plusVal= currVal +1
    s.getRange("A1") .setValue(plusVal)
}

function minus() {    
    ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()    
    s=ss.getActiveSheet()    
    var currVal=s.getRange("A1").getValue()    
    var minusVal= currVal -1    
    s.getRange("A1") .setValue(minusVal)    
}
```

Is there a way to apply it to let's say column from B to H?

I'm just starting with using google sheets and script editor so I don't understand most of the language en tricks of using scripteditor

Answer (score 0):

i think what you are looking for is a loop to run through every column.

```
function plus() {   
    ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()    
    s=ss.getActiveSheet()

//for loop
//r refers to the row (number of rows you have and c refers to column
    for (var c=1; c<(total number of columns+1); c++){
       for (var r=1; r<(total number of rows); r++){
       var currVal = s.getRange(r,c).getValue();
       var plusVal= currVal +1;
       s.getRange(r,c) .setValue(plusVal);
       }
    }
}
```

Basically what happens here is that the referenced range changes each time the loop is completed. go from cell A1 to A2 etc etc, and when the last row is reached, it goes to B1 etc
for your reference, this is the script that i used.

```
function selftest1() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  for (var c=4; c<8; c++){
    for (var r=2; r<13; r++){
    var someCell = activeSheet.getRange(r,c).getValue();
    someCell = someCell+1;
    activeSheet.getRange(r,c).setValue(someCell);
    }
  }
}
```